# Universal App hangs at CreateFileAsync (possible deadlock?)

Tags: c#, async-await, deadlock

I'm making a program that capture photo from camera and perform some actions with it. So I have the following code (handler for camera button and "some actions"):

```
private async void btnCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnCamera.IsEnabled = false;

        var imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        var ocrFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;

        var imgFileRaw = await ocrFolder.CreateFileAsync("ocr_raw.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var imgFileFull = await ocrFolder.CreateFileAsync("ocr_full.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        var imgFilePart = await ocrFolder.CreateFileAsync("ocr_part.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await camera.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, imgFileRaw);
        await camera.StopPreviewAsync();

        await SaveImageEx(imgFileRaw, imgFileFull, false);
        await SaveImageEx(imgFileRaw, imgFilePart, true);

        this.Frame.GoBack();
    }

private async Task SaveImageEx(StorageFile SourceFile, StorageFile TargetFile, bool Partial)
    {
        using (var sourceStream = await SourceFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
        using (var targetStream = await TargetFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(BitmapDecoder.JpegDecoderId, sourceStream);
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(targetStream, decoder);

            bool rotated90Degrees = false;

            switch (previewOrientation)
            {
                case DisplayOrientations.Portrait:
                    {
                        encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;
                        rotated90Degrees = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case DisplayOrientations.PortraitFlipped:
                    {
                        encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise270Degrees;
                        rotated90Degrees = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case DisplayOrientations.LandscapeFlipped:
                    {
                        encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise180Degrees;
                        break;
                    }
                case DisplayOrientations.Landscape:
                case DisplayOrientations.None:
                default:
                    {
                        encoder.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.None;
                        break;
                    }
            }

            if (Partial)
            {
                encoder.BitmapTransform.Bounds = rotated90Degrees ?
                    RecognitionArea1.GetImageRegion(decoder.PixelHeight, decoder.PixelWidth) :
                    RecognitionArea1.GetImageRegion(decoder.PixelWidth, decoder.PixelHeight);
            }

            await encoder.FlushAsync();                   
        }

    }
```

The problem is that 1 of 5-10 times camera button clicked code hangs at line:

> var imgFileRaw = await ocrFolder.CreateFileAsync("ocr_raw.jpg",
>   CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

Please, somebody explain me what is so wrong with my code? I've read lots of examples how to avoid deadlocks with async/await operations and I still don't know where the problem is.

**UPDATE.** It seems without calling "SaveImageEx" there is no hanging, still don't see anything dangerous inside this method.

**UPDATE2.** I made minimal hanging example with the code which I'm really using in the app. Just click camera button for several times and you will see deadlock on "CreateFileAsync":

[HangSample (Visual Studio 2013 solution)](http://www.filedropper.com/hangsample)

Comment: One flaw I see is that you don't do anything to ensure that the button cannot be clicked a second time while the previous async operation is still in progress.  Expecting code to be re-entrant tends to be disappointing.  Simplest way is to disable the button on entry and re-enable it at the end of the method in a finally block.

Comment: What about "btnCamera.IsEnabled = false;" as the first line in the method? Anyway, I'm totally sure that this is not a cause of this problem.

Comment: How far in to `SaveImageEx` do you get before the deadlock?  You might need to add some logging code to find out.  Also, do you still get the deadlock if you remove only one of the two calls to `SaveImageEx`?

Comment: @Brian, I was able to get deadlock even if I replace "SaveImageEx" contents to "await Task.Delay(1000);" (but it occured much more rarely, about 1 time of 20-30 clicking). Also, I have same result if replace "CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting" to "CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists", which make me now to think that this is something time-related... I can make for you test VS2013 solution if you are really interested in.

Comment: @Brian, I've updated my question and uploaded hanging example. Feel free to test it.